# First item in arrayList is always empty and can't be overwritten in a for loop in Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, data-structures

I am new to Data Structure and I am trying to create an arraylist that accepts String values. I successfully created an empty arraylist but whenever I try to run it through a for loop, it returns empty value for the first item. I want to fill up array list with user values from the very first but I could not do it.
I checked other related questions, saw Youtube tutorial but unable to figure out what problem my coding holds?
Here is the snippet of code I tried:

```
public class fire {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter no. of members:: ");
        int size = sc.nextInt();

        ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>(size);

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter names:: ");
            nameList.add(sc.nextLine());
        }
        System.out.println(nameList);
    }
}
```

My output whenever I declare the size prints out empty value for the very first item but I want it to be user-given value.
**outPut**

```
    Enter no. of members:: 
    4
    Enter names:: 
    Enter names:: 
    John
    Enter names:: 
    Cena
    Enter names:: 
    Harry
    [, John, Cena, Harry]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Just add an sc.nextLine(); before the for loop

Comment: Thank you. I overlearnt 7 hours to try to figure it out myself. Thanks a lot.